# Mysql Procedure query error

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, procedure

Porque apenas o `stmt2` não funciona?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE abc_produtos_total_geral(
OUT v_total_geral decimal(14,2), 
IN v_dt_inicial date,  
IN v_dt_final date,
IN v_table_name varchar(40),
OUT v_nome_produto varchar(200))

BEGIN

select sum(iv.valor_total_item) into v_total_geral from vendas v 
left outer join clientes c on v.cod_cli = c.cod_cli
left outer join item_venda iv on v.cod_venda = iv.cod_venda 
left outer join produtos p on p.cod_prod = iv.cod_prod
where status_venda = 1 and dt_venda between v_dt_inicial and v_dt_final;

set @table_name=v_table_name;

set @str = concat('CREATE TABLE `', @table_name,'` 
(
  `cod_prod` int(11) DEFAULT "0",
  `nome_prod` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `total_item` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_intervalo` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percentual` decimal(14,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classificacao` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT "D"
) ENGINE=MEMORY;');

prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

set @str2 = concat('insert into `', @table_name,'` (select 
p.cod_prod, 
p.nome_prod, 
sum(iv.valor_total_item) as total_item,
(DATE_FORMAT(dt_venda,"%m/%Y")) as dt_intervalo,
((sum(iv.valor_total_item)/v_total_geral) * 100) as percentual,
"D" as classificacao
from vendas v
left outer join item_venda iv on v.cod_venda = iv.cod_venda 
left outer join produtos p on p.cod_prod = iv.cod_prod
where status_venda = 1  
group by p.cod_prod, p.nome_prod
order by percentual desc);');

prepare stmt2 from @str2;
execute stmt2;
deallocate prepare stmt2;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Explique melhor a sua dúvida e em português.